# Is the notion of goddess Sarasvati sitting atleast once per day on every beings tongue found in scriptures?

Tags: scripture, belief, saraswati

It is generally said, at least so have I heard in my area, from elders, that goddess Sarasvati sits on every human's tongue, at least once a day. Therefore we should always try to speak about good things since one never knows when the goddess sits on our tongue.

**Is the notion of goddess Sarasvati occupying the tongue once a day found in the scriptures?**

Comment: Due her only we speak/think she is on our tongue everytime

Comment: That can be her vaka shakti, her energy which enables us to speak. I'm asking specifically about her explicit subtle physical presence in the tongue, @Youwillnotknowme